# parleys.com video streaming infrastructure

Tags: java, flash, video, streaming, red5

I was wondering does anyone knows what video streaming infrastructure these guys are using.Front end(gui) is clear which technology these guys are using. On the net I found streaming servers are available, from flash, wowza and red5. From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752262/video-streaming-infrastructure)

red5 seems to have a bit bad reputation, is it so? has anyone used it? how was the experience?

I dont want to use third party host for streaming. Any suggestions to achieve the same on java based technologies.

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 3):

They are using RTMP (Real Time Media Transfer Protocol). You can use [RTMPDump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu) (a free utility) to save streaming media to your disk.